# Online printing related communities

Tags: discussion

Which are some of the most active online communities (regardless of platform) that regularly deal / talk/debate / etc with printing in general?

I'm especially interested in ones focused heavily on DIY and UV printing

I'd love some recommendations if you have any!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, as for January 2021 few links I had on hand are:

- [Reddit r/3dprinter - 3D Printer](https://www.reddit.com/r/3dprinter/)
- [Reddit r/FixMyPrint - Get help to diagnose and fix 3D print problems](https://www.reddit.com/r/FixMyPrint/)
- [SoliForum - 3D Printing Community](http://www.soliforum.com/)
- [Ultimaker Community of 3D Printing Experts](https://community.ultimaker.com/)
- [RepRap Forum](https://reprap.org/forum/)

These are where I personally landed and found something useful when surfing/troubleshooting, and they seem to be actually active. You can query Internet and find many more, but they are not yet on my list *(which is of some value, or not :) here I am nodding to [Trish' comment](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/15399/online-printing-related-communities#comment28989_15399))*.

Comment: RepRap gets my vote...

Comment: @octopus8 Appreciate your taking the time to try and answer. Thanks!